# Launch Main app from MenuBar app

Tags: swift, cocoa, menubar

I've managed to create an Application and I don't want it to be on the Dock until a user clicks the MenuBar Item, then it launches the app and if a user quits the Main app, the menubar Item still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after days of research, I finally figured how to do it.
**Swift 2.3**

```
func toggleApp(sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.window!.visible {
        self.window.orderOut(window)
        NSApplication.sharedApplication().setActivationPolicy(NSApplicationActivationPolicy.Accessory)

    } else {
        NSApplication.sharedApplication().setActivationPolicy(NSApplicationActivationPolicy.Regular)
        self.window!.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        NSApp.activateIgnoringOtherApps(true)
    }
}
```

And this is for keeping the Menubar when the user quits(CMD Q) the app:

```
func applicationShouldTerminate(sender: NSApplication) -> NSApplicationTerminateReply {
    // Cancel terminate if pref set

    self.window.close()
    NSApplication.sharedApplication().setActivationPolicy(NSApplicationActivationPolicy.Accessory)
    return NSApplicationTerminateReply.TerminateCancel
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

in Swift 5:

```
func toggleApp(sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.window.visible {
        self.window.orderOut(window)
        NSApplication.shared.setActivationPolicy(NSApplication.ActivationPolicy.accessory)

    } else {
        NSApplication.shared.setActivationPolicy(NSApplication.ActivationPolicy.regular)
        self.window!.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
    }
}
```